# sql select 1 item from list

Tags: sql

i want to select a column from a table which can have another column reference many times.

```
select t1.name 
from ccp.ENTITIES t1

Non
Albania
Australia
China
Czech Republic
Egypt
Germany
Greece
Group
Hungary
India
Ireland
Italy
Luxembourg
Malaysia
Malta
Netherlands
Portugal
Romania
Spain
Turkey
UK
US
```

this will give me a list of names of which i want 1 row from another table

`v_networks_by_lm` this table holds records with column `t1.name` and `network`. i want the column network only once for each item in the list. `v_networks_by_lm`can hold many `t1.name`

```
entity  name   
a   Spain
b   Spain
c   Spain
d   Spain
e   Spain
f   Spain
g   Spain
h   Germany
i   Germany
j   Germany
k   Germany
l   Germany
m   Germany
n   Germany
o   Germany
p   UK
q   Germany
r   Spain
s   Spain
t   Portugal
u   Portugal
v   Portugal
q   Portugal
```

from the above data which is in `v_networks_by_lm` i only want name  returned once with any value of entity. but i want to pick the name from `ENTITIES` as it can be dynamic

Comment: Sounds like you need a `JOIN`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think aggregation does what you want:

```
SELECT MAX(n.network) as network, e.name
FROM ccp.ENTITIES e JOIN
     ccp.v_networks_by_lm n
     ON n.name = e.name
GROUP BY e.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a subquery to get the single instance of name from the table, and then you do the join against entities.

```
Select sub.one_of_entity_values, sub.name 
from ccp.entities e 
inner join (
    select max(entity) as one_of_entity_values, name
    from v_networks_by_lm
    group by name) sub on e.name  = sub.name
```